# get word from array of characters and compare it with another array

Tags: javascript

i have 2 arrays 1 contains words and second contains letters and multiple of spaces, i want to get all words from letters array note that every words contains 2 letters and more, and after i get the letters i want convert them to word and compare it with the first array if it include the word i have to push it in new array this is the code:

```
let letters = ["a", "b", "o", "u", "t", " ", " ", "d", "o", "g", "s", " ", " ", "v", " ", " ", "n", "o", "t", "e", " ", "m", "e", " ", " "];
let words = ["man","just","dogs","about","me","note","by"];
let newWords = [];
```

Comment: Please write your question more carefully. It's hard to understand the question without the proper formatting. That said, you can do most (if not all) of the things you're asking for with the helper functions provided in the Javascript Array object. You should specially read about `join` and `filter`. Here's the link https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: show us desired output

Comment: i want get words in letters (about,dogs,note,me) and copare it with words in words array if the array include the words push them in newWords array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trivial way that I found to get the words from letters array:

```
let letters = ["a", "b", "o", "u", "t", " ", " ", "d", "o", "g", "s", " ", " ", "v", " ", " ", "n", "o", "t", "e", " ", "m", "e", " ", " "];
let words = ["man","just","dogs","about","me","note","by"];
let newWords = [];

var stringtemp = "";

letters.forEach(element => {
  if (element != " "){
    stringtemp += element;
  }
  else if (element == " "){
    if (stringtemp.length >= 2){
      //You find word separated by one or more space and contains 2 letters and more
      console.log(stringtemp);
    }
    stringtemp = "";
  }
}
);
```

Then, you just have to check at the place of the comment, if the word array contains the stringtemp or not.